# Trying to get an int by wraping it into void* and again wrap it back into Integer but i am not successfull

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Singleton {
    static Singleton instance;
    int num;
    Singleton() = default;

    Singleton(Singleton &) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete;
    Singleton &operator=(Singleton &) = delete;

public:
    static Singleton &GetInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    void* get(){
        return (void*)num;
    }
    void setNum(const int num){
        this->num = num;
    }
};

Singleton Singleton::instance;

int main() {
    Singleton::GetInstance().setNum(12);
    std::cout << *(static_cast<int*>(Singleton::GetInstance().get())) << std::endl;
}
```

So my area of intrest lies in this function

```cpp
void* get(){
        return (void*)num;
}
```

and recieving it inside `int main`

```cpp
std::cout << *(static_cast<int*>(Singleton::GetInstance().get())) << std::endl;
```

But my output is not clear i think it is some udefine behaviour but my goal is to print `12` that is passed already . Help from anybody would be appreciated with proper refrence.

Comment: If you ever feel the need to use C-style casting, then you should take that as a warning that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: And one major problem is that while `get` returns a pointer type, the function itself returns a *value* and not a pointer. So the pointer can't be dereferenced later.

Comment: i agree but exploring new thing is always fun and for `C` style casting is new for me

Comment: When you try to read it, you cast it like so: `static_cast<int*>`, but when you return it, you cast it like so: `(void*)num` (where `num` is an `int`). Don't you see a problem here (that you cast it to two different things, when returning, and when trying to read the value)?

Comment: So you set `num` to `12` then cast that as a `void*` address. When you later try to dereference that value, what do you think will be at memory location `12`?

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you want the `get` function to return a `void*`? It's okay if this is just a case of curiosity and experimenting, but then please state so in the question itself. Otherwise this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return an integer value as a generic pointer (`void*`) then you should really do the conversion in two steps: First to an integer type that is large enough to hold both an integer and a pointer, then in the second step to the generic pointer:

```
void* get()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<std::intptr_t>(num));
}
```

Then when you use the returned pointer, you have to remember that it's really *not* a pointer you returned, but the actual integer value itself. That means you need to do the opposite conversion when using the value, and not attempt to dereference it in any way:

```
auto value_ptr = Singleton::GetInstance().get();
std::cout << static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(value_ptr)) << '\n';
```

I really don't recommend using values as pointers in this way generally. There are a few places where it might be needed, but this doesn't seem to be one of those.

---

Another possible solution is to actually return *a pointer* to the variable `num`:

```
void* get()
{
    return &num;
}
```

As this is actually a pointer, you should dereference it to get the value it points to:

```
auto value_ptr = Singleton::GetInstance().get();
std::cout << *static_cast<int*>(value_ptr) << '\n';
```

Comment: Mate thank you very much for the explanation i am always before unorthodox problems and for me it was one of them but not anymore :)

Comment: You said this is `C` style casting what will be the `CPP` stayle casting then if you can edit your question.

Comment: @UmarFarooq You use C-style casting in `return (void*)num`. I use C++ casting operators.